# To count how many times one row is equal to a value

Tags: r, count, compare

To count how many times one row is equal to a value

1. I have a df here:

```
    df <- data.frame('v1'=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 'v2'=c(1,2,1,1,2),
                 'v3'=c(NA,2,1,4,'1'),
                 'v4'=c(1,2,3,NaN,5),                
                 'logical'=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

2. I would like to know how many times one row is equal to the value of the variable 'logical' with a new variable 'count'
   I wrte a for loop like this:

```
    attach(df)
    df$count <- 0
    for(i in colnames(v1:v4)){
        if(df$logical == i){
        df$count <- df$count+1} 
       }
```

but it doesn't work. there's still all 0 in the new variable 'count'.
Please help to fix it.

the perfect result should looks like this:

```
    df <- data.frame('v1'=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 'v2'=c(1,2,1,1,2),
                 'v3'=c(NA,2,1,4,'1'),
                 'v4'=c(1,2,3,NaN,5),                
                 'logical'=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 'count'=c(3,4,2,2,2))
```

Many thanks from a beginner.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but I strongly suggest you avoid the `attach()` function. There's no need for it in this case at all if you are using `df$` each time.

Comment: I guess the `if` part is not correct in the `for` loop.  it can be `ifelse` `ifelse(df$logical == df[[i]], ..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I guess so far the solution by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59160880/12158757) is an elegant and also the best efficient way to add the column `count`.

Another way (I don't know if that is the one you are looking for the "elegance") you can used to "attach" the column the `count` column to the end of `df` might be using `within`, i.e.,

```
df <- within(df, count <- rowSums(df[1:4]==logical,na.rm = T))
```

such that you will get

```
> df
  v1 v2   v3  v4 logical count
1  1  1 <NA>   1       1     3
2  2  2    2   2       2     4
3  3  1    1   3       3     2
4  4  1    4 NaN       4     2
5  5  2    1   5       5     2
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rowSums` after creating a logical `matrix`

```
df$count <- rowSums(df[1:4] == df$logical,  na.rm = TRUE)
df$count
#[1] 3 4 2 2 2
```

Comment: thank you very much! but I would to attach this result on the df in a elegent way. I will appreciate if there is a further answer.

Comment: @sylvia  If you meant the `attach` function, please don't use that

Comment: @sylvia do you mean something like `df <- within(df, {count <- rowSums(df[1:4] == logical,  na.rm = TRUE)})`?